# Numpy array - multiplying each column by one another

Tags: arrays, numpy

I would like to know the fastest way to multiply each column of a `numpy` array by one another and return a new `numpy` array consisting of these just-built columns - all `2`-element combinations from `n`-element set of columns.

Comment: not 100% clear what you're asking for? so you have an MxN array as input. What dimension is the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good starting point

```
import numpy as np

I, J = np.triu_indices(n)
A[:,I] * A[:,J]
```